# How can I handle the error "certificate verify failed: certificate has expired" in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm just starting to create an image classification program in Python with TensorFlow using the CIFAR10 dataset, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HPwo4wnJeA) tutorial. Here is my code so far:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

I'm getting an error as follows:

```
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1257, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1303, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1012, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 952, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1426, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)
```

What does this error mean, and what can I do to fix it? I'm a beginner with TensorFlow and haven't been able to find an exact solution for this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently had a similar error using python `3.7` and just turned off the verification like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

Check out this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33285) for more information. You can of course try to install the missing certificates for your Python version. I can confirm that your code works on Google Colab. So it is definitely due to some missing certificates.